# Help with 200k record limit for SOQL query (query selectivity error)

Tags: apex, soql, query

We are experiencing an issue around an insert and update for Opportunity Line Items. When creating/updating the OLI, a class is called to creates/updates records on a custom object. The error message is received because a query is run on the custom object and the custom object has over 200k records.

The code was created by a consulting firm and we don't have any devs to help us fix this. Was wondering if this is a quick fix that we could handle with our very limited knowledge of APEX or would we require someone to come in?

Here is the error message:

*execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times) Class.AutoScheduling.CreateSchedules: line 206, column 1 Trigger.OpportunityLineItemTrigger: line 46, column 1*

Here is the part of class containing the SOQL query.

```
        String theQuery = SOQL_SCHEDULE_QUERY_PT1;
    for (AutoScheduler_Mapping__c s : theCustomSettingMapping.values()) {
        //v1.1 - Check to make sure the field isn't contained in the mandatory fields
        // so taht we prevent duplicate field errors
        if (!theOppScheduleSet.contains(s.Opportunity_Line_Item_Schedule_Field__c.toLowerCase())) {
            theQuery += ', ' + s.Opportunity_Line_Item_Schedule_Field__c;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: We would need to see a complete example of the SOQL query, as well as details about your data model, field types and indices, total volume, etc, to make an attempt at triaging this issue. That said I think it's unwise to attempt to resolve this type of issue without a developer available to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, David.